# How to create many divs without actually creating them individually

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, web

I'm working on a project with html, css and js and I want to create many divs (let's say, 200) so, how can i create them without actually writing code for 200 different divs... I know I can do it with js but could I do it only with html and css..?

Comment: That is not possible with only HTML and CSS. You will have to use JavaScript or a HTML preprocessor

Comment: And how can I do it with JavaScript...? Should I loop 200 times and then create items inside it...?

Comment: If the divs should be static after page load, you can also use PHP, that‘s even easier than using js

Comment: Not sure about your context and what you mean with "writing", but in a code editor, you can use copy + paste and auto completion.

Answer (score 1):

As I already said in my comment, you can't do it without JavaScript.
A JavaScript solution would be the following:

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");

for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  const item = document.createElement("div");

  item.classList.add("item", "item-" + i);

  container.appendChild(item);
}
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: .3rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way with js:
you can create one HTML **Span Element** and with js you change the content of it. I bet with that knowledge you find something

Answer (score 0):

how it's going? Html or css is not a programming language. So you can't do some kind of automation or repeating code or something like that. The only way to do that sort of things is using Javascript. Here is how:

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- let's say we trying to add divs here. -->
</div>
```

And here's script:

```
function addMultiple (where, what, count, callBack) {
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    // creating elements with document.createElement() method
    let item = document.createElement(what)
    // and then adding them into "where" element.
    where.appendChild(item)
    
   /*
    and finally we'll have a function called Callback.
    This is just gonna take our item as an argument and 
    do some stuff on it according to what we want.
    (I'll show a simple usage down below)
    */
   callBack(item)
  }
}

// let's say we want to add 200 divs into "container" element 
// and then we want to add class name to those divs.

const container = document.querySelector('.container')
addMultiple(container, 'div', 200, item => {
  // this code will be repeated for all divs.
  item.classList.add('what_ever_you_want')
})
```